# Solr return only parent document on child query match

Tags: java, solr, lucene, parent-child

I have a set of documents indexed which has a pseudo parent-child relationship. Each child document had a reference to the parent document. Due to some availability complexity, these documents are not being indexed to support block-join, i.e. instead of a nested structure, they are all flat. Here's an example:

```xml
<doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field name="title">Parent title</field>
  <field name="doc_id">123</field> 
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">2</field>
  <field name="title">Child title1</field>
  <field name="parent_doc_id">123</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">3</field>
  <field name="title">Child title2</field>
  <field name="parent_doc_id">123</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">4</field>
  <field name="title">Misc title2</field>
</doc>
```

What I'm looking is if I search "title2", the result should bring back the following two docs, 1 matching the parent and one based on a regular match.

```xml
<doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field name="title">Parent title</field>
  <field name="doc_id">123</field> 
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">4</field>
  <field name="title">Misc title2</field>
</doc>
```

With block-join support, I could have used Block Join Parent Query Parser,

```
q={!parent which="content_type:parentDocument"}title:title2
```

Transforming result documents is an alternate but it has the reverse support through `ChildDocTransformerFactory`.

Just wondering if there's a way to address query in a different way. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: In [the reference documentation of the BlockJoinParser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers) is a note about the use of which about the use of `which`. Probably there is the way to go?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you use Solr 6, you might be able to expand the results to include the parent records using [Graph query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-GraphQueryParser).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately we are still at 5.0, so graph parser is not an option